# Delphi XE Indy TIDSMTP and gmail : Socket Error 10060

Tags: delphi, gmail, indy

I'm having this 'Socket Error 10060 - Connection timed out' when trying to send emails using TIDSMTP, on a Delphi XE application. The same code works on a Delphi 2007 application on the same machine. No firewalls or anti-virus software installed. Same DLLs used on both applications (libeay32.dll / ssleay32.dll).

Here is my code :

```
idsmtp1.host = 'xxxx'; 
idsmtp1.port = 465;
idsmtp1.username = 'x';
idsmtp1.password = 'x';
with ssl1 do
      begin
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
      Destination := 'smtp.gmail.com:465';
      host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
      //OnStatusInfo := ssl1statusinfo;
      end;
idsmtp1.iohandler := ssl1;
idsmtp1.usetls := utUseImplicitTLS;
idsmtp1.UseEhlo := true;
idsmtp1.connect; // here the exception is throw
```

Comment: Do not set `ssl1.Destination` and `ssl1.Host` manually. `Connect()` assigns them for you. Aside from that, try setting `idsmtp1.Port` *after* setting `idsmtp1.UseTLS`. Setting `UseTLS` *may* change the `Port`, so you want to make sure your chosen port is actually used. If that does not work, try using `utUseExplicitTLS` on port 587 instead.

Comment: Removed 'ssl1.destination' and 'ssl1.host' and moved the port to the end of the code. Did not work on 465 and 587 / utUseExplicitTLS. But it's working on Delphi 2007... Is there any difference on XE / 2007 , can it use the same DLLS ?

Comment: Here are a bizarre thing : after i put a breakpoint on  'onStatusInfo' of ssl1 , it stopped there for many times, and the message was sent ! I found out with the breakpoint, it works, without no... It's like it need some 'pause' to work. Does it make sense ?

Comment: I can confirm that adding some 'pause' on 'onSatusInfo' of ssl1 solved the problem. I just added this : 'sleep(500);application.processmessages', and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but adding some 'pause' in the event 'onStatusInfo' of TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL fixed the problem. Here is the code added :

```
procedure ssl1StatusInfo(Msg: string);
begin
sleep(500);
application.processmessages;
end;
```

Without this code i always got the 'Socket Error 10060 - Connection timed out'.

Comment: Hey delphirules thank you! BTW if you're not using SSL then you can use the IdIOHandlerStack and post the sleep code into the OnStatus event. It actually works and you don't get a timeout error.